# Split function across multiple fields in BigQuery SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I have data like this:

[image]

Each column will have the same number of elements across a row, where the first element in the first column corresponds to the first element in the second column etc.

How can I flatten this to get the below?

[image]

With a single column I am able to do this by combining a `CROSS JOIN` with an `UNNEST` but I cannot get this to work with multiple columns since the join ends up creating multiple variations and `UNNEST` loses the order of the array so I can't match them.

If I were building the arrays from scratch, I would use some kind of `STRUCT` element in there, but I can't find a way of doing this when the arrays are created from a `SPLIT()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WITH_OFFSET` is your friend here:

```
WITH strings AS (
  SELECT "a,b,c" a, "aa,bb,cc" b
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "a1,b1,c1" a, "aa1,bb1,cc1" b
)

SELECT x_a, x_b
FROM strings
  , UNNEST(SPLIT(a)) x_a WITH OFFSET o_a 
  JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(b)) x_b WITH OFFSET o_b
  ON o_a=o_b
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for BigQuery Standard SQL is shown below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'a|b|c' col1, 'n|o|p' col2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'd|e', 'q|r' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'f|g|h|i', 's|t|u|v' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'j', 'w' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'k|l|m', 'x|y|z'
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  SPLIT(col1, '|')[SAFE_ORDINAL(pos)] value1, 
  SPLIT(col2, '|')[SAFE_ORDINAL(pos)] value2
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(col1, '|')))) pos
```

with expected result

```
Row id  value1  value2   
1   1   a       n    
2   1   b       o    
3   1   c       p    
4   2   d       q    
5   2   e       r    
6   3   f       s    
7   3   g       t    
8   3   h       u    
9   3   i       v    
10  4   j       w    
11  5   k       x    
12  5   l       y    
13  5   m       z
```